# Mongoose Model.deleteMany() only deletes first element of matches

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to use the Model.deleteMany() function from mongoose. I'm trying to do something like this:
`MyModel.deleteMany({"_id": {$in: ['objectid 1', 'objectid 2'`
But this only deletes the first element of the matches from DB (in this case, if 'objectid 1' exists in the DB, it deletes that, but if it isn't nothing happens (both n and deletedCount is 0 in the returned data from the function). I tried using something other than the _id as a query, and this worked. If I had three elements with the same 'name' field, I could delete these.

I tried _id both with and without quotation marks. I also tried converting the object id strings to actual object ids before passing them to deleteMany, but this had no difference either. I have also of course tried to google this, but everything I've found are examples of usage, where it looks like I'm doing the exact same thing as the various blog posts.

I haven't added much code here because I don't really see what else I could be adding. I'm already printing out the input to the $in object, and this is correct. The strangest thing, I think, is that the first element of the list is deleted. Is it treated as a deleteOne request for some reason? are there any config options I need?

As per request, I've added the query and the documents I'd hope to delete:

```
//Request
MemberModel.deleteMany({"_id": {$in: [
  5ee4f6308631dc413c7f04b4,
  5ee4f6308631dc413c7f04b5,
  5ee4f6308631dc413c7f04b6
]}};
//Expected to be deleted
[
{
    "_id": "5ee4f62f8631dc413c7f04b5",
    "firstName": "Name",
    "lastName": "Nameson",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "5ee4f62f8631dc413c7f04b6",
    "firstName": "Other",
    "lastName": "Person",
    "__v": 0
}
]
```

If you have any ideas for what I could try, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: What are the types of values stored in _id fields and used in your query? Strings do not match ObjectIds.

Comment: In the _id fields there are ObjectId's, and also in the query. I've tried both with strings and converted to ObjectId's. I've found that the Model.method()s often do those sorts of conversions themselves, such as with .findById(). @D.SM

Comment: In that case provide the full actual queries and documents you expect ot find.

Comment: Added now @D.SM

Comment: Your query does not look like legal JS code.

Comment: It is. I'm using Mongoose Models, which take parameters like that. Here is an example: https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/mongoose-delete-many-by-id-932

Comment: In the example you linked, ids are quoted.